# Inserting data in the MySQL table having variable/undefined number of coloumns using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, web-applications

I am trying to build a web application where user can create their own list which will be saved as tables in MySQL database.User can have n number of coloumns as per their requirement.

User is able to create a list, everything's working so far.

Here is the code to generate form from user's list  :

```
<?php
require 'con.php';
$list_name=$_GET['list'];       //get list name
$fields=array();
    $sqlz = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $list_name";
    $resultz = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlz);
     while($rowz = mysqli_fetch_array($resultz)){
        array_push($fields,$rowz['Field']);           //grab all the list coloumn and pushed in array
        }
        if(isset($_POST['btn'])){ 
            $i=1;
            $data=array();
            while ($i<sizeof($fields)){
                $grab=$_POST[$fields[$i]];       //grabbing all the data enterd by user on form        
                array_push($data,$grab);
                $i++;
            }
            //how sould i insert data to mysql here ?
            // solution code goes here
            }
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>LiGen By Project Club</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Fill The Form of :
        <?php echo $list_name;?>
      </h2>
      <form method="post">
        <?php
          $i=1;
        while($i<sizeof($fields))
          {
         ?>  <!–-Creating form as per the list coloumn -–>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<?php echo $fields[$i];?>">
              <?php echo $fields[$i];?>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Enter <?php echo $fields[$i];?>" name="<?php echo $fields[$i];?>">
          </div>
          <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name='btn'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My question is : How can I insert the data into MySQL table from form where there are variable number of fields ?

I want to trigger the code when 'btn' is pressed.

Table Name : $list_name  ,
Columns : $fields (array) ,
User Input from form : $data (array)

Please help me out.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. You are letting users create/remove columns?

Comment: I'm the user , The db is on my pc and there is no plan to deploy it. I'm trying something .

Comment: Okay, then I guess you could select a row from the table, iterate over it once and you'd know all the columns present. This scenario could never be stable in the real world though.